# Unable to enter UEFI with on boot (With F2/F12)

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

Symtom is somewhat like this. [BIOS is broken (?)](https://superuser.com/questions/603877/bios-is-broken)

I can still enter UEFI Setup using `efibootmgr -n` on Linux, however press <kbd>F2</kbd> according to what shown on the screen does nothing. Same for <kbd>F12</kbd> (that is to select Boot Menu)

I'm planning to reinstall Windows, I can still using `efibootmgr` again but I'm afraid that it's one way trip, if the installation broken, there is no way to select a proper boot loader again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's definitely the problem with firmware corruption. After reinstall Windows 8 and flash the firmware, it works now, both F2 and F12.

Comment: You should write a detailed answer below if you've solved the issue. You can self-accept it too.

Comment: I realized you've fixed the problem, but be aware there's *no* standardization in EFI user interfaces -- F2 or F12 might work for you, but the keys to enter the firmware setup utility may be totally different on another computer. Specifying your make and model may be important for questions like this. As to the rest, boot loader information stored in NVRAM sometimes gets corrupted, leading to symptoms similar to what you've described. Clearing unused boot entries sometimes fixes the problem. This is basically a buggy firmware issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm thinking of writing a better explanation just in case someone else having the same situation...